# Convert datetime from UTC to IST in google sheet using query funtion

Tags: sql, datetime, google-sheets, utc, google-query-language

I have the column shown in the figure I just want to convert the datetime column from UTC to IST I am trying to add 05:30:00 to each row using google query_language but couldn't find a way
Please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb4KX.png)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10+"5:30:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your dates are placed in A:A, try this QUERY:

```
=ArrayFormula(
 QUERY(IF($A:$A="","",SPLIT($A:$A&";"&TIME(5,30,0),";")),"SELECT Col1+Col2 LABEL Col1+Col2 'RESULT' FORMAT Col1+Col2 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:dd'")
)
```